# How to avoid spacer in NavigationView with Forms?

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I have an `NavigationView` with an `NavigationLink`, when I get to the second View I have a strange spacer between the head and the beginning of my form:

[image]

This is my code:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Hallo")){
                        Text("abc")
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("abc")){
                        Text("lorem")
                        Text("ispsum")
                        Button(action: {
                            //UIApplication.shared.open(eintrag.eintrag.url as URL)
                        }) {
                            Text("starten")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Hello")

        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? How to avoid this? Its only when navigation in. If I set the view as my start view it looks like it should:

[image]

What do I need to do to get in on the top?

Comment: The View is wrapped in NavigationView twice, just remove it from SampleView - it already has one from its parent view.

Comment: perfect thank you. post this as an answer and I will accept it.